# ComponentArt unlicensed version error even with a valid license

Tags: componentart

I'm working on a legacy application that uses these third party controls. I'm moving the application to new infrastructure but the ComponentArt UI elements are reporting that they are unlicensed, shown in the image here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbLxM.png). We have the license in the bin folder and I have tried to install the available ComponentArt nuget package to no success.